# how does a ball mouse make a cursor move and how does it send signals when it moves?

Tags: mouse

can someone please tell me clearly 100% how does the cursor move when the ball mouse moves(not optical please not optical)

all I know is that when you move the cursor then ball the rotates and somehow it sends signals from that disk thing with holes BUT HOW??

**how does it send signlas from that disk thing with holes**

you see I want to understand 100% from the point you turn the computer on to the point a cursor moving. how does a mouse move 100% explanation if you can

IF YOU CANT EXPLAIN 100% THEN FEEL FREE TO TELL WHATEVER YOU CAN

Comment: Welcome to superuser. You're asking a bunch of extremely basic questions that are trivially googlable - which is probably why they arn't being well recieved. I'd suggest [help] and consider asking questions about practical issues, rather than asking questions on how stuff works with no research effort. I'd add too many closed questions might result in restrictions in your ability to ask questions.

Answer (score 3):

A ball inside the mouse touches the desktop and rolls when the mouse moves. The underside of the mouse's logic board: The exposed portion of the ball touches the desktop.

Two rollers inside the mouse touch the ball. One of the rollers is oriented so that it detects motion in the X direction, and the other is oriented 90 degrees to the first roller so it detects motion in the Y direction. When the ball rotates, one or both of these rollers rotate as well. The following image shows the two white rollers on this mouse: The rollers that touch the ball and detect X and Y motion

The rollers each connect to a shaft, and the shaft spins a disk with holes in it. When a roller rolls, its shaft and disk spin. The following image shows the disk: A typical optical encoding disk: This disk has 36 holes around its outer edge.

On either side of the disk there is an infrared LED and an infrared sensor. The holes in the disk break the beam of light coming from the LED so that the infrared sensor sees pulses of light. The rate of the pulsing is directly related to the speed of the mouse and the distance it travels. A close-up of one of the optical encoders that track mouse motion: There is an infrared LED (clear) on one side of the disk and an infrared sensor (red) on the other.

An on-board processor chip reads the pulses from the infrared sensors and turns them into binary data that the computer can understand. The chip sends the binary data to the computer through the mouse's cord.

Source: [Here, first result on google btw](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/mouse2.htm)